# Get Image Src from image title

Tags: jquery, imagesource

Hi i have strange requirement of getting `image src` from `image title` using jquery.
In my case image title are all different so there is no possibility of same image title.

Let me clarify the question. Here is one image tag.

```
<img title="Lion2" alt="Lion2" src="http://localhost/test/img/co/122.jpg" class="awp_pcp_square_img">
```

i am getting title Lion2.

Now i what i want is get `src` of this image tag.
I can not do this by class as there are multiple image tag with the same class name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get element by any attribute and use [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the src value.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/33rRQ/)**

```
$('img[title=Lion2]').attr('src');
```

> **Description:** Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

You can also use indexer [] to get the DOM element are directly access the attribute value without using `attr()`

```
$('img[title=Lion2]')[0].src;
```

Comment: thanx for such a fast reply. let me try this.